# no symbols found in /usr/bin/uname - error while running perf

Tags: linux, perf

I have generated perf.data file using following command 
`sudo -E perf record --call-graph dwarf python3 script.py`

This was successful. After generating `perf.data`, I wanted to generate report from it. So I executed following command :

```
sudo perf report --stdio --header > perf_report_py.txt
```

However, it results in following error message

```
no symbols found in /usr/bin/uname, maybe install a debug package?
```

I installed `kernel-debuginfo` and `kernel-debuginfo-common` packages. But the error still persists. Can anyone please help me fixing this?

Comment: Pretty sure that's a warning you can safely ignore in your case.

Comment: Why would `kernel-debuginfo` include symbols for the user-space binary `/usr/bin/uname`?  You might want kernel debuginfo for kernel symbols recorded during system calls, but IDK why you think it would fix that warning.  Anyway, is the actual perf output not what you want?

Comment: Okay. I was wrong then. That was what I found when I googled the error.